# Tweeting a quote

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

I have coded a random quote generator and want to be able to share the quote to twitter.
http://codepen.io/nachamuami/pen/KrRYpY
by trying to tweet the function it is calling up the whole function to twitter and not the quote generated by the code. Any pointers will be much appreciated.

```
 function getQuote(){
var arrayLength = quoteArray.length; //number of entries in array
var randomValue = Math.floor(Math.random()*arrayLength);
var newQuoteY = quoteArray[randomValue].yiddish;
var newQuoteE = quoteArray[randomValue].translation;

 $('#inYiddish').html(newQuoteY);
 $('#inEnglish').html(newQuoteE);};



 $('#quote-button').click(function(){
             getQuote();           
}); 



$('#twitter-button').click(function(){
           window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + getQuote);
        });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The statement

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + getQuote);
```

is actually appending the function itself to the URI. JavaScript compensates by taking the string form, which in this case is more or less the exact declaration you made for `getQuote`, albeit as a string.

You may have meant the following:

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + getQuote());
```

In this case you are still going to encounter an error, as `getQuote` does not have a return value, and thus the tweet will simply say `undefined`. To correct this, you'll need to return a string in `getQuote`. Alternatively, you could have `newQuoteY` and `newQuoteE` be declared outside `getQuote`, but still set by it. This would allow for something like the following, wherein the currently displayed Yiddish quote is tweeted.

```
window.open("https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=" + newQuoteY);
```

Comment: Thanks, I ended up defining the newQuotes outside the function. but now I ran into another issue, if i try tweeting the first place holder quote it comes up undefined.

Comment: @AharonHyman You'll have to set the original value of `newQuoteY` to be the initial quote or you could grab the value of `$('#inYiddish').text()`. I'd personally go for the former to avoid the needlessness of an extra DOM query to get something that in most cases was previously set by the JavaScript anyway.

Comment: @AharonHyman A neater way still would be to run `getQuote()` once on pageload, which would also have the added bonus of a different quote everytime the user opens the page.

Comment: Great, thank you! I also added a second tweet button for the English quote